# Alternative for deleting an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

In many cases I don't feel like deleting a wrong answer, mostly because of useful comments.  The answer together with its comments often provides a good learning material, as in: see how this mistake is easy to make, and see comments explaining *why* it is a mistake.

Can there be an alternative to deleting answers?  For instance, such "almost deleted" answers would always be displayed last and probably dimmed and/or collapsed.

EDIT: Another thing I forgot to tell.  When deleting a wrong answer with comments I often feel uneasy because I indirectly delete other's correct comments only because of *my* mistake.

Comment: Note that starting with 10k reputation you can see deleted answers.

Answer (score 9):

If I am in this situation , I <s>point out to them that I am never wrong, and can't possibly be in this instance either</s> use strikeout text to strike out the incorrect portions of my answer.

I then <s>eat crow</s> add some text to the bottom of the answer explaining my new position, giving credit where deserved.

In my case, this situation <s>never</s> hardly ever occurs. :)

Comment: It's hard to strike out code snippets, for instance.

Comment: I have a friend who claims, and I quote: "I'm never *wrong*, I'm just sometimes less than 100% correct."

Comment: If you really want to keep the bad code in the answer, you can put `// BAD CODE!` and `//END OF BAD CODE` comments in it, I suppose.  As with all things, communicate your intent clearly and effectively.

Comment: @Aarobot: *I once thought I was wrong, but I was mistaken.*

Comment: How do you do the *strikeout*?

Comment: @dboarman put `<s> </s>` around the code you want to strike out

Answer (score 4):

Some people make their answers Community Wiki and leave a note saying "here is what you *shouldn't* do", so that they don't continue to lose reputation from downvotes for a wrong answer.

If it's wrong, it will very likely get downvoted, and after a few downvotes it will become dimmed and appear last, exactly as you suggest.  If it's CW, then you don't lose any rep for this.

Although speaking personally, I don't feel that it's a really appropriate use of the wiki system, I'm just mentioning what *some* people do.  I'd just delete the answer, because ultimately a wrong answer is simply noise.  I do understand the perspective of wanting other people to learn from your mistakes, but most people simply won't get that far, they'll look at the accepted answer or top 2-3 answers and then move on.

Worse, if your answer has upvotes, leaving it up can be actively harmful; some people may not realize that it's been left up "for posterity" and actually attempt what you've suggested.  Especially when it comes to code snippets, people have a *remarkable* ability to ignore anything and everything around the code while they copy and paste.

I know it's hard to delete an upvoted answer, but most of the time you'll be doing the readers a favour.

Comment: Well, if such "almost deletion" was implemented, it could work as normal deletion wrt reputation: at least remove all upvotes and rep. from them, maybe also stop rep. loss from downvotes.  Another problem with deleting answers for me is that I feel like it is deleting other people's work (the comments) only because of *my* mistake, not theirs.

Comment: @doublep: I can assure you, as someone who writes a lot of comments, that I don't get upset when an answer I commented on is deleted.  In fact, most of the time, when I leave a comment to the effect that the answer is wrong/unhelpful/misleading, I *expect* them to either fix it or delete it.  So don't worry about us; we don't earn rep from comments and I'm pretty sure that very few of us are emotionally attached.

Comment: Anyway, people with > 10k rep can still see your deleted answer, so it's not *permanently* gone.

Comment: And leaving a comment on why you deleted an answer can be helpful and is appreciated, for that reason.