# How to flag rude and/or irrelevant comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

From an admittedly cursory reading of [Updated comment flagging - Supporting the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct) I see that much has been said and, apparently, done about "rude" comments.

Personally, though, I can cope easily with "rudeness" because I just ignore it. But what I find *extremely unpleasant* to cope with is **irrelevance** because I feel compelled to answer. Out of politeness but of course also just in case the person making the comment might eventually give a useful answer.

In some cases the author clearly just wants to show off. However, it is most often a matter of the author of the comment *not* having read the question.

For an example, see my question at [Can an air-intake fan stop smoke wafting through a brick common wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139604/can-an-air-intake-fan-stop-smoke-wafting-through-a-brick-common-wall)

**Question:** Is there a way to flag a comment as **irrelevant**? Perhaps something like: "*Please* re-read the question"?

**Note.** This is quite different from [How to remove irrelevant answers to posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97116/how-to-remove-irrelevant-answers-to-posts)

Comment: As mentioned, "no longer needed" is the best. However, I find it terribly phrased—because it implies that it was *once* needed, which is not at all true in every case. It should simply be "not needed."

Comment: Maybe takes a bit more time but you can always raise a custom flag, explaining that you were unsure which stock reason to apply to get the comment removed.

Comment: @Jason Bassford  I totally agree and vote for "not needed"

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to flag a comment as irrelevant?

*In general*, as @Anne Daunted suggests, use the "no longer needed" option. As Shog9 explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/295232):

> The middle flag - "no longer needed" - is new, and is intended to cover all of "too chatty", "obsolete", and the non-abusive uses of "not constructive".

The subtext used to be "this comment is obsolete, chatty or *otherwise unnecessary*" (emphasis mine); even though the wording slightly changed since [Updated comment flagging - Supporting the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct), it's still the same flag. [This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag/298420#comment949512_292042) seems to suggest you shouldn't worry about "not needed" vs. "no longer needed".

---

However, it seems like you want to have multiple comments removed here. In such a case, it might be better to use a custom moderator flag (on the post or on one of the comments you want to have removed), explain the situation and why you think these comments do not help in [improving the post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Also, if you see a single user repeatedly leave borderline unfriendly/rude comments, you can use a custom flag to bring this unwanted behaviour to ♦ moderators' attention.

Comment: If I use a custom flag for cherry-picking which comments to delete (or keep) I prefer a custom post flag instead of a custom comment flag as the former allows for 500 characters, the latter only 200 and if you include links you run out of space in no time.

Comment: I do not think "_hav[ing] multiple comments removed_" is necessary because, once the first comment that is beside the point is removed, I think potential commentators will be more likely to read---and, if they can, address---the question. But I agree with Jason Bassford that "no longer needed" is heavily misleading or, at the very least, very obscure and completely ... beside the point. By contrast, "Not needed" is perfectly _neutral_ and would likely be quite effective in that it would intrigue the commentator whose attention it would thus direct back to the question.

Comment: "not needed" may be interpreted by somebody as "never needed", which doesn't include "no longer needed".